# event dispatcher using std::unique_ptr and std::deque in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unique-ptr, deque

I have just written the source code below to dispatch events properly by using std::unique_ptr and std::deque, but I am not sure how accurate it is. I know it is not a good question but could someone evaluate it, is there any weird issue? In addition, I don't have any performance concern.

Thanks in advance.

- Volkan

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Event {
public:
    Event(int a) : m_a(a)
    { }

    void print()
    {
        cout << m_a << endl;
    }

private:
    int m_a;
};

class EventQueue {
public:
    unique_ptr<Event> pop()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
        unique_ptr<Event> p = nullptr;
        if (!m_Queue.empty()) {
            p = move(m_Queue.back());
            m_Queue.pop_back();
        }

        return p;
    }

    void push(unique_ptr<Event> p)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
        m_Queue.push_front(move(p));
    }

private:
    deque<unique_ptr<Event>> m_Queue;
    mutex m_Mutex;
};

EventQueue evq;

void EventHandler()
{
    while (true) {
        unique_ptr<Event> p = evq.pop();
        if (p)
            p->print();
        else
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread first (EventHandler);
    while (true) {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        unique_ptr<Event> ev(new Event(a));
        evq.push(move(ev));
    }

    first.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does `EventHandler()` exit?

Comment: @imreal, it will last forever

Comment: If you can use C++11, replacing raw `unique_ptr` construction then push with just: `evq.push(std::make_unique<Event>(a));` is slightly better form (if you can avoid ever using `new` and `delete`, you're golden), and by making it a natural rvalue, it can optimize out the local variable entirely, constructing directly to `push`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `std::make_unique` is C++14... I'm wondering why it has not been added in C++11. Weird... Oo

Comment: @S.Clem: Oops, my mistake there. `make_shared` is C++11, `make_unique` is C++14. They made `make_shared` earlier presumably for the performance boost (it can allocate both object and refcounting structure as a single block, where `shared_ptr<...>(new X)` cannot) and later realized that exception safety made it a good idea and added `make_unique` for that reason.

Comment: I tried your example too, it has a good practice from my point of view.